# How to build libgit2 and php-git2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: compiling, git, libraries, make, cmake

I need to build and install [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) and [PHP-Git](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git) from source. This is my first time doing something like that and I'm not so experienced with linux.

1. i followed the instructions on github. when i try `cmake` .. it doesn't find libcurl, http-parser and libssh2.
2. i installed libssh2-1, libssh2-1-dev, libhttp-parser, libhttp-parser-dev and libcurl4-openssl-dev.
3. i executed `cmake --build .`, changed in the php-git2 dir executed `phpize` and ./configure `--enable-git2-debug`:

   `configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
   checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... failed`
4. when i then try `make` it shows many errors like `unknown type name...`, `redundant redeclaration of ...`, `previous declaration of ... was here`, `warning: enumeration value ... not handled in switch` and many undeclared stuff

It would be great if someone could help me, Thanks.

**EDIT: it seems that you can't build php-git. I tried many things and nothing worked**

Comment: I went to their GitHub repos and they have clear instructions on how to compile.

Comment: not for me, i'm pretty new in this stuff and dont want to do something wrong

Comment: Then what kind of help are you looking for? You haven't specified it yet.

Comment: i dont know... i even dont know how to use make and cmake... i only get plenty of errors and warnings.
first i downloaded both, then i changed in the directory of libgit2 and made `$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
$ cmake --build .`

Comment: If you tried the instructions given in the GitHub repos and came across error messages and warnings, please edit your question and include all these details. Help us help you and don't be vague.

Comment: i followed the instructions on github and on [https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/build-and-link/](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/build-and-link/). when i try `cmake ..` it doesn't find libcurl, http-parser and libssh2. do i have to install them via apt-get?

Comment: Please put all these details **and the error messages** in your question instead of as comments.

Comment: sorry, i edited the question